# Conversion fails when converting the varchar value '65' to data type int

Tags: sql-server-2008, crystal-reports-xi

SQL Server 2008 and Crystal Reports XI

I'm not exactly sure why I can't convert the values.  I have tried cast and convert which both result in the same error.  This column did initially contain alphanumeric values but after my primary query inserts values into a temp table there are only numbers in there.

The conversion

```
CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(myfield) = 1 THEN CAST(myfield AS INT) ELSE 0 END
```

returns zeros.  An example of the data in the column is:

65
89
151
175
210

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but I can't figure it out.  In crystal reports I was able to successfully use:

```
IF isnumeric({myfield}) then tonumber({myfield}) else 999
```

That converts successfully without any issues.  Why would it work in crystal and not in SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was there was a hidden carriage return in the varchar column so I used:

```
REPLACE(myfield, CHAR(13), ''),
```

and was able to convert it without any trouble.